# jquery mobile button is not hiding in style

Tags: jquery-mobile

hi we are working on jquery mobile how to hide button with css not with code we are using display:none in style but its not working for jquerymobile
here is the code we are using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
         <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Buttons</h1>
            <button data-role="button" style="display:none;">hello</button>
         </div>
         <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is  to wrap your button in a DIV and then just hide/show it.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <button data-role="button">hello</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #pageone .ui-header > .ui-btn{display:none;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Try editing the property like "display: none !important".
If its not worked yet, then Check whether you had declared "display: block !important;" property for buttons.
 (or)
write individual style in internal /external stylesheet like,

`#pageone .ui-header > .ui-btn { display:none !important; }`

If you want to move with code, change "display: none" to `visibility: hidden`
or

`$( ".target" ).hide();`

This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css("display", "none")`, except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown, it will once again be displayed inline.